# PHP combine and count associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Our software supplies a purchased product list in an associative array. We need to combine this array and create a new array with consolidated count.  This array will then be used by to create a purchase list for our billing department.

**Sample Array:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [item] => Long Sleeve-Shirt & Hooded Sweatshirt
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => Youth Small
        [color] => Blue
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item] => Long Sleeve-Shirt & Hooded Sweatshirt
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => Adult Small
        [color] => Red
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [item] => Hooded Sweatshirt Youth & Adult Sizes
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => Youth Large
        [color] => Blue
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [item] => Long Sleeve-Shirt & Hooded Sweatshirt
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => Youth Small
        [color] => Blue
    )
}
```

**Consolidated Array**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [item] => Long Sleeve-Shirt & Hooded Sweatshirt
        [quantity] => 2
        [size] => Youth Small
        [color] => Blue
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item] => Long Sleeve-Shirt & Hooded Sweatshirt
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => Adult Small
        [color] => Red
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [item] => Hooded Sweatshirt Youth & Adult Sizes
        [quantity] => 1
        [size] => Youth Large
        [color] => Blue
    )

}
```

How would I create a function to combine the first array down and create the second array. The only thing I could think of is to create several foreach loops and slowly break the lists down.  I have not worked with associative arrays and functions and I believe doing multiple foreach loops would be a slow and can be done much more efficient.

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is no question? How could anyone answer? I could solve it for you, but I don't understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're not so much combining or consolidating arrays so much as removing duplicates. The question becomes, what are your conditions for entries being duplicates? Does every field have to be exactly the same? It looks like a yes from reading your question. Since you nested arrays here (as opposed to an array of objects), it sounds to me like you need a good hash algorithm for fingerprinting. You could go with a [PHP native cryptographic hash algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php), but you really don't need them to be cryptographically secure. I would take a look at [murmurhash](https://sites.google.com/site/nonunnet/php/php_murmurhash), but there are [other options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions).

PHP has a function that would handle this, but it does not work on multidimensional arrays: [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

You could also use the php hashtable-like implementation of arrays to do this for you. Given that you only have 4 fields, you're probably not going to run into much problem, but you very well might...

But your code would look like this:

```
// given an array with keys for item (string), size (string) and color (string),
// produce a unique fingerprint value identifying it
function hashProduct(array $product) {
    // Concatenate all the fields of the product array
    $key = $product['item'].$product['size'].$product['color'];

    // Add the length of the key to the end of the hash to reduce collisions
    return ((string)murmurhash($key)) . strlen($key);
}

// Assume $originalArray is passed in populated with the structure you provide above
// Build a consolidated array, selectively adding to it.
public function consolidateProductsList(array $originalArray) {
    $consolidatedArray = array();

    foreach($originalArray as $product) {

        // fingerprint the product
        $hash = hashProduct($product);

        // You could also just do this:
        // $hash = $product['item'].$product['size'].$product['color'];
        // php treats string-type array keys as hash maps

        if(array_key_exits($consolidatedArray[$hash]) {
             // Still a chance of collision here, but it is very small
             // You should try to handle it or at least report it
             $consolidatedArray[$hash]['quantity'] += $product[quantity];
        } else {
            // Product has not been encountered yet
            $consolidatedArray[$hash] = $product;
        }
    }

    return $consolidatedArray;
}
```

A collision in a hash function is where you have two inputs that generate the same hashed output, but are not equal to each other. The way to detect it is do the long form comparison, in this case: `$product1['item'] === $product2['item'] && $product1['size'] === $product2[size]` etc.

I've not run or even checked that code for errors in php, but hopefully it's enough to get you started, minus fixing whatever bugs or typos I made.

Comment: After a bunch of corrections is worked like a charm.  Thanks for the great example.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution is to define exactly what fields you want to group on and which field should hold the summation:

```
function consolidate(array $data, array $group_fields, $sum_field)
{
    $res = array();

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        // work out a hash based on the grouped field names
        $hash = '';
        foreach ($group_fields as $field) {
            $hash .= $item[$field];
        }
        // perform summation if item hash matches
        if (isset($res[$hash])) {
            $res[$hash][$sum_field] += $item[$sum_field];
        } else {
            $res[$hash] = $item;
        }
    }

    return array_values($res);
}

print_r(consolidate($data, array('item', 'size', 'color'), 'quantity'));
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rwH0Dg)